# Instantiate new javascript based on dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a tricky problem to solve and so far I havent found a good solution for it. Sorry, I am a newbie at JS.

I have a dropdown that selects a time duration 1 hour, 2 hours etc. I am trying to switch what script I am going to run based on the dropdown. Am running into some issues.

My simplified html looks like this

```
<div id="content">
  <h2>Some Stats</h2>
  <section><div id="legend"></div></section>
  <div id="chart_container">
    <div id="graph"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- My graph generates above "legend", "chart_container", and "graph". time_duration is a variable that is generated by the dropdown-->
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    //dropdown
    $("#DateFilter").change(function(){
       var current = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("id");
       graph = new graph("path_to_url" + current); 
       graph.render();
    });
  });
</script>
```

When I try to change the duration, the new graph based on new timeframe is generated but is overlayed on top of the current one.

This is because "legend", "chart_container" and "graph" divs are still from the old one. Also the graphs keep running continuously (use setInterval).

Can I just replace the entire current graph with the new one WITHOUT resorting to using multiple divs for each of them (and using hide, show) using JQuery?

Comment: I suppose you could clear the existing `div` with `$('#graph').html("");` before calling `graph.render();` - is that what you mean?

Comment: Exactly what I was going to post: ie. Clear the html within the current element that you are drawing to

Comment: @ochi I was about to say the same thing. It's difficult to provide better guidance based on the code that's currently posted.

Comment: Thanks, Ochi. Seems to be working just the below jquery alternative. But, it complains about something like: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null

Comment: my guess is that `.empty()` attempts to remove children nodes (that may, or may not exist?)... The first time you create the graph, this `$('#graph')` probably doesn't exist, giving you the error.  You could check for it beforehand:  `if( $('#graph').size() > 0 ){ $('#graph').empty();}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jQuery you can use the method `empty()`:

```
$("#graph").empty();
```

Then you can add the new content.

READ MORE: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_empty.asp

Comment: Thanks. Seems to be working, but, am hitting into a lot of errors such as this: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null

Comment: If it's `empty` there is no more child, that's why `removeChild` will be taken as an attempt of remove a non-existing property.

Comment: So, I guess its ok to ignore it?

Comment: I don't know. I would have to see the code to know, but you can look for where is `removeChild` and what is being used for, or placing the `empty()` method after `removeChild`. It depends.